# how to post some data in url in iphone app to get the required result

Tags: php, iphone, mysql, xcode

I am getting data from severs in json format but i want that user should send user_id while calling the json service so that it should show the desired result i am using following code

how to call the data from iphone by post passing the user_id
PHP CODE

I have used

```
   $user_id=$_POST['user_id'];
   $query = mysql_query("SELECT s.*, u.user_id FROM survey_master AS s
JOIN user_profile AS u on u.user_id = s.user_id where s.user_id=$user_id");

    $rows = array();
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
   $rows[] = $row;
   }
  echo json_encode($rows);
```

iPhone Code

```
  NSArray *tempArray =[[DataManager staticVersion] startParsing:@"http://celeritas-solutions.com/emrapp/surveyDescription.php"];

for (int i = 0; i<[tempArray count]; i++) {

    id *item = [tempArray objectAtIndex:i];
    NSDictionary *dict = (NSDictionary *) item;
    ObjectData *theObject =[[ObjectData alloc] init];
    [theObject setSurvey_title:[dict objectForKey:@"survey_Title"]];
    [theObject setSurvey_Description:[dict objectForKey:@"survey_Description"]];    
    [theObject setDate_Created:[dict objectForKey:@"date_Created"]];

    [surveyList addObject:theObject];
    [theObject release];
    theObject=nil;
}
```

Comment: You could have searched for sending parameters to PHP and you would have found the answer. There are MANY questions on SO similar to this and MANY tutorials on the internet that explain this. I suggest you try reading some of them so you at least have a basic understanding of what you are doing. Also (and this is **important**) PLEASE read up about SQL Injection. Your code is dangerous

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use GET for sending user_id.

At PHP;

```
$user_id=$_GET['user_id'];
```

AT IPhone;

```
  NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://celeritas-solutions.com/emrapp/surveyDescription.php?user_id=%@", user_id];
  NSArray *tempArray =[[DataManager staticVersion] startParsing:url];
```

Comment: for e.g i have user id in NSString like 100 how to give that in url

Comment: You can build a NSString with your user_id. I improved answer accordingly.